# Transformation error ... parser plugin(s): 'decorators-legacy, decorators'

Tags: jscodeshift

I get the following error when I run `jscodeshift -t ./react-codemod/transforms/React-PropTypes-to-prop-types.js ./src`

```
Transformation error (This experimental syntax requires enabling one of the following parser plugin(s): 'decorators-legacy, decorators' (13:0))
```

I googled a bit and found out I have to set the `--parser-config` of jscodeshift. I need help with a sample json file that can resolve the above error.

Comment: I followed these instructions https://github.com/ember-codemods/ember-module-migrator/issues/86 to solve my problem to codemod the react code

Answer (score 2):

The instructions mentioned in the comment by The Third are correct.
I was need to manually update `babel5Compat.js` file with this `'decorators-legacy'` plugin.

```
// in ./node_modules/jscodeshift/parser/babel5Compat.js

plugins: [
    // a list of plugins,
    'decorators-legacy',
]
```